# comparation of lists in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a task where i need compare 2 lists and assign similar part to other list, so i write this:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

c = []


for i in range (0,13, 1):

    if a[i] == b[i]:
        c.append(i)
    print (c)
    
print (c)           

print (a)
```

but sublimetext say

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
[0, 4]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\code\pop.py", line 10, in <module>
        if a[i] == b[i]:
        IndexError: list index out of range
```

what wrong with this code? (i very-very newbie)

Comment: What do you mean by similar elements? (same element on the same index?)

Comment: The error occurs because the a list does not have 13 elements.

Comment: You're looping 13 times but there are only 11 elements in your a list, so it fails as it can't index after that.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the intersection of the two lists?  That would be `c = list(set(a) & set(b))`, or maybe something like `c = [x for x in a if x in b]`

Comment: It's helpful in questions like this to provide the desired output because things like `similar part` don't mean the same things to the same people. I would say `1, 2, 3` but it doesn't seem like that is what you are coding for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a loop to run through 13 elements, but `a` has only 11 elements.  Look up the error message for details.

To fix the problem, stop your iteration at the index of the shorter list:

```
for i in range (min(len(a), len(b))):
```

This is at your current programming level.  To raise the bar a little, use `zip`:

```
for a_val, b_val in zip(a, b):
    if a_val == b_val:
        ...
```

Comment: or just `c = [x for x, y in zip(a, b) if x == y]` for a one-liner!

Comment: ... which raises the bar a little more, using a **list comprehension**.
You're welcome to edit that into my answer.

Comment: I think it's misleading to talk about this in terms of "levels" -- it's just straightforward, idiomatic Python.  You don't need to get your Python orange belt certification before you're allowed to use a list comprehension.  :)  The impulse is to think of it as more "advanced" because it's less obvious to those of us who learned other languages first, but if you remove that bias I think it's easier to just do things the simple ("Pythonic") way.